# How to set a shader node property for Blender material via Python script?

Tags: python, blender

[image]

Above is the material I've created. I exported my model to .obj from Blender. From a Python script (I have Blender compiled as a Python Module), I import my .obj file.
I then attempt to set the `Noise Texture` `'W'` property:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.import_scene.obj( filepath = PATH_TO_MY_OBJ)
bpy.context.object.name = "obbb"
obj = bpy.data.objects["obbb"]
```

My material is called `Material`. How can I access the `Noise Texture` node and change the value of `W`?

I want to access the 'Noise Texture' node via python, so that I can randomize the 'W' property.

Answer (score 2):

```
    # accessing the materials
    material = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")
    
    # accessing all the nodes in that material
    nodes = material.node_tree.nodes
            
    # you can find the specific node by it's name
    noise_node = nodes.get("Noise Texture")

    # available inputs of that node
    # print([x.identifier for x in noise_node.inputs])
    # ['Vector', 'W', 'Scale', 'Detail', 'Distortion']

    # change value of "W"
    noise_node.inputs.get("W").default_value = 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).